Why GAN discriminator results are so different if real and fake images are in the same batch or not?
I'm training a GAN to generate small images and I wanted to incorporate the minibatch stdev improvement to avoid that all generated images by generator tend to be the same.
The implementation of MinibatchStdev is taken from this great article: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-train-a-progressive-growing-gan-in-keras-for-synthesizing-faces/
My code, however, is not a progressive-growing gan but a static one generating images of 32x32 right now.
What I found is that when I implement the training gan function putting real and fake images in the same batch I'm getting reasonably good results. However, when I separate fake and real images in two batches to train the discriminator, what I get is a very poor result.
Code with real and fake images in the same batch:
def train_gan(generator, discriminator, gan, dataset, batch_size, codings_size, noise8x8_dim=4, noise16x16_dim=0,
              noise32x32_dim=0, n_epochs=5, start_epoch=0, model_version=0, specific_model=''):
    # generator, discriminator = gan.layers
    for epoch in range(start_epoch, n_epochs):
        print(f"Epoch: {epoch + 1} / {n_epochs}")
        loss_d = []
        loss_g = []
        for X_batch in dataset:
            # 1. Train discriminator
            inputs = []
            noise = tf.random.normal(shape=[batch_size, codings_size])
            inputs.append(noise)
            if noise8x8_dim:
                inputs.append(tf.random.normal(shape=[batch_size, noise8x8_dim]))
            if noise16x16_dim:
                inputs.append(tf.random.normal(shape=[batch_size, noise16x16_dim]))
            if noise32x32_dim:
                inputs.append(tf.random.normal(shape=[batch_size, noise32x32_dim]))
            generated_images = generator(inputs)

            real_images = X_batch * 2 - 1  # Adapt real images between -1 and 1 because generator uses tanh as activation

# critical part of the code:
            X_fake_and_real = tf.concat([generated_images, real_images], axis=0)
            # y1 = tf.constant([[0.]] * batch_size + [[1.]] * batch_size)
            y1 = tf.constant([[0.]] * batch_size + [[1.]] * len(X_batch))

            discriminator.trainable = True
            l_d = discriminator.train_on_batch(X_fake_and_real, y1)
            loss_d.append(l_d)

            # 2. Train generator
            for i in range(2):
                inputs = []
                noise = tf.random.normal(shape=[batch_size, codings_size])
                inputs.append(noise)
                if noise8x8_dim:
                    inputs.append(tf.random.normal(shape=[batch_size, noise8x8_dim]))
                if noise16x16_dim:
                    inputs.append(tf.random.normal(shape=[batch_size, noise16x16_dim]))
                if noise32x32_dim:
                    inputs.append(tf.random.normal(shape=[batch_size, noise32x32_dim]))

                y2 = tf.constant([[1.]] * batch_size)
                discriminator.trainable = False
                l_g = gan.train_on_batch(inputs, y2)
                loss_g.append(l_g)


        l_g = np.mean(loss_g)
        l_d = np.mean(loss_d)
        print(f"loss_d: {l_d}, loss_g: {l_g}")


As I said, the previous code obtains reasonable results but the generator tends to lose variability and generate always the same image independently of the random inputs.
To avoid this, I want to use the minibatch stdev and I think that discriminator should be trained with real and fake images batches separated.
So, I change the "critical" part of the code by this one:
            y_gen = tf.constant([[0.]] * batch_size)
            y_real = tf.constant([[1.]] * len(X_batch))
            l_d = discriminator.train_on_batch(real_images, y_real)
            loss_d.append(l_d)
            l_d = discriminator.train_on_batch(generated_images, y_gen)
            loss_d.append(l_d)`


However, when I traing the GAN separating real and fake images the results after many epochs are still random ugly images, it is like there is no training at all. In addition, loss_g and loss_d decrease very quick in this second version, and I don't understand.
Can somebody give me an idea of why the learning is totally lost when I separate fake and real images in different batches?
I tried to change the order (first fake and then real) and the opposite. I tried also to train discriminator with one batch of fake images, then generator, and then discriminator again with real images. None of this variations help.

Does your discriminator use BatchNormalization?

Yes, after every conv2D layer. Do you think this may be the cause?

I commented all batch normalizations I had in the discriminator and I can tell you that definitely it was the issue. Thank you so much @xdurch0

Cool, in case you want to know more details, I could recommend this post -- not putting this as an answer since link-only answers aren't good for SO, but it might help anyway.

Note that in practice it may be enough to remove BN only from the first layer.
